# Gitlab pipeline fails to handle directories containing dots (.)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using a self-managed Gitlab and try to make my first pipeline work with little success. I have a group runner that uses docker.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - ls -l

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd $(ls -d *.FileProcessor/)
    - dotnet build $(ls -d *.csproj/)
```

The `ls` is there so I can see the files in docker. The output of `ls` is the following (I include only the main things here):

```
total 136
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root  4096 Dec 13 21:36 Database
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root  4096 Dec 13 21:36 Libs
...
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root  4096 Dec 13 21:36 Service.FileProcessor
```

If I simply try to `cd` into Service.FileProcessor I get the error "`/bin/bash: line 144: cd: Service.FileProcessor: No such file or directory"` even though the folder is there! So I made an ugly workaround: `cd $(ls -d *.FileProcessor/)` and it works.. The problem is this project references another one which relative path is ../Service.Common/. Since this directory name also contains a dot (.) I get a lot of reference errors during build stating that this project rerefence cannot be resolved. The weird thing is that if I remove the dot from the directory name the thing seems to work. Any explanation or workaround on this issue?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not able to reproduce this issue using a brand new project on gitlab.com with shared runners. When you say "The problem is this project references another one which relative path" I'm not sure what you mean. Are the projects in the same repository, or do you mean another GitLab project in a different repo?

Comment: They are in the same repository. Actually I found that folders and project names shouldn't include dots, without them my pipelien works.